# How to justify product integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lp-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ be  function.

Can we say that

$$\int_{[a,b]\times[c,d]} f(x) dx=\int_{[c,d]} \left(\int_{[a,b]} f(x_1, x_2) dx_1\right) dx_2$$?

Comment: Not every function has an intergal. With suitable hypothesis this follows by Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: Have a look at the Fubini theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: if $f$ is absolutely integrable on its domain then yes by fubinis theorem.